# Apiary blueprint markdown for an array response body

Tags: jsonschema, apiblueprint, apiary

I have a REST service that returns an array of Strings (i.e. not an object). The relevant Blueprint markdown from Apiary is as follows:

```
+ Model (application/json)

    + Body

            [
                "element1",
                "element2",
                "element3"
            ]

    + Schema

            {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
```

When I run the mock service in Apiary it works, but I get the following error in apiary traffic inspector:

```
This API request was compared to a documented resource but was found invalid. 
Check your request headers and body below. 
... 
JSON schema is not valid! invalid type: object (expected [object Object]/array) 
at path "/items"
```

Is there a trick to get this working (a change to the markdown), or is this a bug with Apiary?

Comment: This isnt valid JSON schema. Try use [JSON Schema Generator](http://www.jsonschema.net/) for make schema from data.

Answer (score 0):

Apiary support JSON Schema draft 3, this using JSON schema generator - http://www.jsonschema.net/

`{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
    "required":false,
    "properties":{
        "0": {
            "type":"string",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/0",
            "required":false
        },
        "1": {
            "type":"string",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/1",
            "required":false
        },
        "2": {
            "type":"string",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/2",
            "required":false
        }
    }
}`

Comment: That schema won't allow an array - it's expecting JSON like this: `{"0": "element1","1": "element2","2": "element3"}`

Comment: Compare in jsonschema.net, array and object. Array have properties option and object none.